# Orders below 30,- pay 7,- / above 30,- delivery free

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

there are two options: pickup and deliver

pick up there are no delivery costs (duh)
when choosing deliver then orders below 30,- you need to pay 7,- and above 30,- delivery is free.

how can I do this?

do I need to use the picetable?

magento 1.7.0.2

---

## EDIT

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 2 separate payment methods.
One for self pickup. You can use the free shipping module for that. Just change the title to "Self pickup".
And for the second one use `Table rates`.
Your rates should go like this.
Use 'Price versus destination' as the condition and your csv with the rates should look like this:

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
   *   ,     *      ,          *      ,           0.0000           ,     7.0000
   *   ,     *      ,          *      ,           30.0000          ,     0.0000
```

Remove the spaces. I added them for visual effect.
Just keep in mind that you can upload the table rates csv on the website level. So go to `System->configuration->shipping` methods and select a website from the top left selector.

Comment: hey, I have added this but somehow when having an order above 30,- it still adds 7,-. The CSV is correct. Did I miss a setting or is it a cache problem?

Comment: its not a cache problem. any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: 30 means subtotal. Are you sure the subtotal is above 30 or is somewhere between 23 and 30 and it adds 7 and then it goes over 30?

Comment: no my subtotal is 64 and adds 7,- :( I have added screendumps in first post

Comment: pritty weird, it makes no sence, it shouldn't add the 7,-

Comment: Seams strange to me too. What you did seams OK. Remove all the products from the cart and try again. That's my last idea

Comment: No luck, really must be a bug then damned :( thanks for helping. I'm out of ideas aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using Mganeto free shipping, you can follow on here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-free-shipping

you can use Minimum Order Amount

**Minimum Order Amount : Sets the minimum order total that must be met in order to qualify for free shipping. Setting this value to 0 will allow free shipping on all orders.**

Comment: That one is used for Pick up yourself. It costs 7,- when order below 30,- so if I'm correct I can't use this.

Comment: here is on of my fav modules, I have tested on 1.8 and it works http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pickup-at-event-multiple-flatrates.html

Comment: thanks Ahmed, I'm first trying to use the method Marius gives.

Comment: He is the KING :)